# Is it possible to mange AWS on Google App Engine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Say I want to schedule EC2 instant start up, or something like this.

I did some reading on the Google App Engine document, find that scheduler is supported, however I am not familiar with Google API, before I do further investigation, maybe I can get a quick answer whether it is feasible and practical? Or any issue I should take consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview, you can issue HTTP connections from a GAE application, so connecting to the EC2 API should be possible.  In fact, there was an issue in 2011 about using boto (the python EC2 api implementation) on AppEngine that claims it works now: https://code.google.com/p/boto/issues/detail?id=115

Comment: Thanks David, looks like it should work but with possible limitations and issues.